# using SUM and presenting result as absolute (ABS)

Tags: sql

I have both positive and negative numbers (money) in a column and need to:

1. SUM the total ie. SUM(myColumn) based on if the numbers are +/-
2. Present the result as an absolute ie. even though the result is -1234 it should be presented as 1234

SQL is not my trade as you probably notice but we've solved most other issues but this one so any help is appriciated. Keep in mind my skill level is very low

Comment: if you are happy that an answer solves your problem, you should be able to accept it (by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to use a combination of the `sum` and `abs` aggregate functions in SQL. Since you want the absolute value of the sum, the `sum` function will need to be called inside the call to `abs`:

```
select abs(sum(columnName)) from table
```

That should work for both SQL Server, MySQL, and Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Try one (or more) of these

```
SELECT SUM(moneyColumn) FROM MyTable
SELECT SUM(ABS(moneyColumn)) FROM MyTable
SELECT ABS(SUM(moneyColumn)) FROM MyTable
```